# Load the files from latest folder from azure blob storage to azure data warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure and I get 150 CSV files everyday through SFTP into blob storage and they are stored in separate containers everyday. The containers are numbered as 0000,00001,00002 with daily files. How do I load the files from the latest folder into azure data warehouse. How do I point the copy activity to point to the latest folder dynamically. What is the best way to do it? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is a bit too broad (and I'm not sure what copy activity you're referring to). How you load data into your data warehouse is really up to you (there is no one single way), but as far as knowing about new content arriving in blobs, you might want to look into Event Grid, which has the ability to send notifications when new content arrives. There is documentation written on this.

Comment: One additional question that I have is that is a new blob container created every day for the files that are coming in. If that's the case, then can't the blob container be named as the date (following the naming convention of course) so that it's easier to identify them.

Comment: @Gaurav - Yes, the blob container is created every day for the files that are coming in. I can't change the name of the containers. I need to access the latest container. Is there any max function in metadata to get the latest container? How do I do that? Please advise

Comment: Are the containers always named in sequential order? For example, if the container created today is named `0000` will the name of the container created tomorrow be `0001`? Or it could be completely random?

Comment: Hi Guarav, yes they are named always in order.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no direct way to find the latest blob container.

Considering a new blob container is created each day and the blob container name is in sequential order, only way to find the latest blob container is to list all blob containers in the storage account, either take the last blob container in the result set or sort the result in descending order and take the first one to find the latest blob container.

There's a `Last Modified Date` property on a blob container but again this changes any time the blob container is changed so you can't really use it reliably to find the latest blob container. Again for this you would need to list the blob containers (you simply can't avoid this step).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. How do we get the list of containers from SQL server? Is there an easy way? Please could you advise. Thank you.

Comment: Are you storing this information in a SQL Server? That would make the job easier actually. I was under the assumption that you're simply pushing the data from SFTP to Blob Storage. You would use `List Containers` API operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2) to list the containers. Can you edit your question and include the complete process? I might have to change my answer.

Comment: Sorry Gaurav for the confusion. I am not storing this information on SQL server. We get the data from SFTP to blob storage and stored in folders in sequential order and I need to take the files from the latest container and load it into data warehouse. That is my requirement. I am not sure what is the best and easy way to do it. Please ignore my previous question. As suggested by you, how do I list the containers in descending order and take the top 1. Please advise.

Comment: You will need to write some code to do that. You could use any of the available Storage Client SDKs. Look for `ListContainers` or similar method. This would give you a list of blob containers in a storage account. Once you get the list, you simply need to sort them in descending order or take the last item in that list.